# Распознавание метода

Tags: c++

```
class A;
class B
{
B(...):(...){}
...
};
class A
{
B x ();
B y ();
}
```

Как в классе B узнать, какой метод класса A его вызвал: x или y ?????

Comment: По моему ответ единственно возможный: методы `x` и `y` должны явно об этом сообщить, передав соответствующий параметр.

Comment: Пожалуйста поясните как метод может вызвать класс?

Comment: Такой вопрос указывает на недостатки дизайна. Знание должно быть направлено в другую сторону. Если поведение `B` различно в зависимости от использования его в `x` или `y`, добавьте в `B` свойство (или параметер конструктора) и устанавливайте (подавайте) нужное значение в каждой ситуации.

Comment: x и y без явных параметров

Comment: @ДоСтОеВсКиЙ Включите в вопрос минимальный компилируемый пример, который демонстрирует проблему вместо вашего некорректного кода.

Comment: Но код в `x` ведь знает, что он находится в `х`.

Comment: @Igor и как тогда сделать?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow че в нем некоректного?

Comment: @ДоСтОеВсКиЙ - Вам не виден мой комментарий выше, или в нем что-то непонятно?

Answer (score 3):

```
class B
{
public:
    B() : origin('\0') {}
    B(char origin) : origin(origin) {}
private:
    char origin;
};

class A
{
public:
    A() {}
    B x() { return B('x'); }
    B y() { return B('y'); }
    B xx() { return B(); }
    B yy() { return B(); }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b1 = a.x();
    B b2 = a.y();
    B b3 = a.xx();
    B b4 = a.yy();

    return 0;
}
```

Других способов я не вижу. Узнать, какой функцией созданы `b3` и `b4` - нельзя.

По мотивам комментария @Igor ))

Можно устроить некоторую "защиту", объявив `B(char)` как `private` и сделав классы A и B друзьями. Тогда в `main` нельзя будет написать `B b5('x');` и по состоянию поля `origin` можно будет однозначно судить о создании экземпляра `B` внутри A.

Comment: @ДоСтОеВсКиЙ, а ответ принять?